# Do bananas prevent cancer?

Tags: cancer, prevention, fruits, carcinogens

I found this article: https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/fstr/15/3/15_3_275/_pdf , but I am not sure whether it means that bananas prevent cancer.

Comment: No, it doesn't say that.